# Animation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At this stage my code is broken since the last part is not working correctly. 
I'm trying to make the content and the blue eagle come down to their original place. The green eagle needs to be hidden before the blue eagle and the content come down. 
I've tried making a new function (so far without success). Since I'm new at this, all the help I can get is welcome. 
Please see this link for a live example: http://www.epicforever.com/contact

Html:

```
    <div class="curtain_green"></div>
    <div class="curtain_blue"></div>
    <div class="eagle_green"></div>
    <div class="eagle_blue"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').on("submit", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    $(".eagle_blue").css({ top: "-130px" });
    $(".eagle_green").animate({"top": "-130px"}, 2200);
    $("#content").animate({"top": "-120px"}, 2200, function() {
        $("img.bg_blue").fadeIn(3500);
        $(".curtain_blue").fadeIn(3500);
        $(".eagle_blue").fadeIn(4300);
        //$('form').fadeOut(2800);
           $(".eagle_blue").animate({"top": "-10px"}, 2200, function(){
            $("#content").animate({"top": "0"}, 2200);    
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: looks like you just need to hide the green eagle

Comment: Tried that. Didn't know where to put that. 
And also the blue eagle and content are coming down 1 by 1. I want them to come down together.

Comment: Just hide the green eagle right before you animate blue eagle. To have the content come down at the same time as the eagle blue, take the content out of the callback and put it underneath the eagle blue animation, like so:
$(".eagle_green").hide();
$(".eagle_blue").animate({"top": "-10px"}, 2200);
$("#content").animate({"top": "0"}, 2200);

Comment: Added your code and what happens is that the form goes up and comes down right away. But I want the blue eagle to load fully first and THEN have the blue eagle and the content come down together. Without the green eagle showing. 

I added your code to the js.file Please see the transitions now on the website: http://www.epicforever.com/contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sequencing is wrong...

Try this to see if it's working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').on("submit", function (e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var vSpeedMove = 2200;
        var vSpeedTransform = 3500;

        $(".eagle_blue").css({ top: "-130px" });
        $("#content").animate({"top": "-120px"}, vSpeedMove);
        $(".eagle_green").animate({"top": "-130px"}, vSpeedMove, function(){
            $(".eagle_green").fadeOut(vSpeedTransform);
            $("img.bg_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform);
            $(".curtain_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform);
            $(".eagle_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform, function(){
                $(".eagle_blue").animate({"top": "0px"}, vSpeedMove); 
                $("#content").animate({"top": "12px"}, vSpeedMove);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Please note that in the last two lines I have changed the position of the form and eagle to end exactly in the dame position which they started :

```
$(".eagle_blue").animate({"top": "0px"}, vSpeedMove); 
$("#content").animate({"top": "12px"}, vSpeedMove);
```

If you need them to be the way they were before, please change the position to what they were before.

So, here is the code break-down for more explanation:

1- I added two variables for timing in case you wanted to change the timings you only have to change the values of these two variables:

```
var vSpeedMove = 2200;
var vSpeedTransform = 3500;
```

2- animate the content of the form and the green eagle up:

```
$("#content").animate({"top": "-120px"}, vSpeedMove);
$(".eagle_green").animate({"top": "-130px"}, vSpeedMove, function(){
```

look ad the callback function at the end of the second line. it means that, after the animation - moving up - finished, do the things in the function. so the code will wait until the green eagle moves up and then continues to the rest.

3- fade out the green eagle and simultaneously fade in the blue eagle and curtain and background:

```
$(".eagle_green").fadeOut(vSpeedTransform);
$("img.bg_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform);
$(".curtain_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform);
$(".eagle_blue").fadeIn(vSpeedTransform, function(){
```

again pay attention the the callback function at the end of the fourth line. it means that when the blue eagle has completely faded in, then do the thing in the function.

4- animate the blue eagle and form down:

```
$(".eagle_blue").animate({"top": "0px"}, vSpeedMove); 
$("#content").animate({"top": "12px"}, vSpeedMove);
```

and that's all. hope this break-down has helped you...

Comment: Not working correctly either. 
What happens is that you see the green eagle disappear and for a moment there is no eagle at all. And the content is coming down while the eagle is turning blue and hasn't even come down. 
So no, this code is also not good.

Comment: OK, can you please tell me what exactly do you have in your mind?
When the green eagle is disappearing does the blue eagle should appear at the same time or what? again I'm saying the sequencing is wrong and if I know the correct sequence, I may be able to help you...

Comment: Step 1: Green Eagle + Form will go up. 
Step 2: Everything becomes blue (background + eagle)
Step 3: Blue eagle + Form will come down to their original position where they started in the beginning of the loading of the webpage. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, My question is about step 2. in this step what exactly will happen? 1- green background and eagle will suddenly disappear and blue background and eagle will appear? 2- first green elements will fade out with a timeout and then blue elements will fade in with a timeout or 3- while green elements are fading out, blue elements fade in simultaneously?

Comment: Just now I have made some changes in the code too meet your requests. please give it a try and update me if it works fine or not...

Comment: Perfect! Works fine. 
Can you please explain what I was doing wrong here?

Comment: great, as I mentioned before, you had to work on your sequencing, I will edit the post and explain what is happening in the code...

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was twisting and turning it for hours.